# Display selected row data from UITableView in UIButton

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I wrote this code to display the selected item from `UITableView` on `UIButton`. The problem is that `UIButton` title is not changing on selecting row but it changes after clicking on another item and put the label of button for the first selection.

How can I directly display the data on a click ot a `UITableView` row.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    countryButton.setTitle(names[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Note : names is my array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    countryButton.setTitle(names[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you implement it in `tableView: didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`, you should implement it in `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` instead. Be careful with the names. :)

Comment: Thank you really I didn't see that :D